# Python cannot find module in the same folder

Tags: python, module, spotipy

I have `spotipy` installed on python3, and when I run it, it calls the `__init__.py` file, but then that file attempts to import from client, and it says that client can not be found, although `client.py` is in the same folder as `__init__.py`.

I'm wondering if the issue lies in the fact that I have multiple versions of python installed?

EDIT: The working directory only has the file I'm running, which as of now simply says "import spotipy". Also, I checked, and it seems like the `__init__.py` file is unable to import anything else in the folder.

Comment: A package is declared with a ``__init__.py`` file in a folder; not ``init.py``.

Comment: Is there also a `client.py` in the current working directory?

Comment: @JamesMills that appears to have been a formatting issue, surrounding a word with `__` makes it bold, unless it is marked as code: __init__.py (not marked as code) and `__init__.py` (marked as code).

Answer (score 1):

As James said, you need to place empty file `__init__.py` in your folder. Then Python will think of this folder as of a package and you will be able to do your imports.